# Flatten a JSON array column to distinct result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select from a table with JSON array column

```
Id  Name   ListCol
-------------------
1   test1  [1,2,3]
2   test2  [4]
3   test3  [1,4]
4   test4  [2]
```

If I query:

```
SELECT [ListCol] 
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable]
```

it returns

```
[1,2,3]
[4]
[1,4]
[2]
```

What I expect is

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use *distinct* with *openjson*

```
select distinct j.value
from t
cross apply OpenJson(ListCol)j;
```